# PHP MySQL to PHPExcel is not showing data

Tags: php, phpexcel

/* it works but when I open the excel sheet its not working so I deleted the echo in the else statement and the whole else so it worked but without printing data into the sheet */

```
include_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$sheet = new PHPExcel();


$servername =
$username = 
$password =
$dbname = 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phonenumber FROM people where answer='true' LIMIT ".$start.",10 ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        $activeSheet=$sheet->getActiveSheet();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $activeSheet->setCellValue('A1',' $row["firstname"]');
        $activeSheet->setCellValue('B1','$row["lastname"]');
        $activeSheet->setCellValue('C1','$row["phonenumber"]');
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();         
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output'); 
exit;
```

Comment: Is it showing anything at all? What is the error you get, what do you expect?

Comment: it shows excel error when I open it error in type ... but when I remove the else statement it works without printing data to the sheet

Comment: Don't put your password in a public forum!

Comment: I deleted that , It was a mistake

Comment: Do you really want to write every row from the database to row 1 in the screadsheet? But if you're getting a blank sheet, then make sure that your SQL query is actually returning data

Comment: no but I dont know how to show all of the data in many rows I didnt use the library before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

In this code

```
$activeSheet->setCellValue('A1',' $row["firstname"]');
```

statements, you shouldn't use any quotation marks around the `$row` part, remove them:

```
$activeSheet->setCellValue('A1', $row["firstname"]);
```

Also, your `else` clause outputs data before the header causing incorrect data being sent. Remove the `else`. If there is no data, you just end up with an empty Excel file.

Finally, you put all data in the same cells over and over again. Use a variable to increment to rownumber:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = ...) {
    ...
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A'+$i, $row["firstname"]);
    ...
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Oh It worked !! but how can I print the values all of them ... now its just showing the data to the first row in excel only the first item !

Comment: You write all data in these same cells over and over again. Use a variable to increment the row. I'll update my answer.

Comment: it worked but why when I retrieve numbers and when its converted to excel its copied as Hexadecimal ?